# How to retrieve a value from another program Java

Tags: java

I have something like this, This is program 1:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program1{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner Lecture=new Scanner(System.in);
Program2.main(new String[0]);
}
}
```

And this is program 2:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program2{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner Lecture=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many years do you have?");
int age = Lecture.nextInt();
}
}
```

obviously, this is an example, but i need to run program 2 from program 1 to enter some data and then retrieve the value from program 2 to use in program 1. How can i do this?

Comment: First: learn basic Java object-oriented programming concepts so that rather than having to deal with two clunky static main methods, you can have objects interacting in a clean way.

Comment: Why do you have to start a separate process? Can't you simple import the other program (as Jar) and use it as part of your own?

Comment: I think we need more information. What is the context that these two programs are running in? Are they desktop apps? Web apps? And why do they have to be two separate programs, rather than two classes in a single program?

Answer (score 0):

Write a method something like below in the Program 2 and call from Program 1.

```
public static int getAge(){
Scanner Lecture=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many years do you have?");
int age = Lecture.nextInt();
return age;
}
```

If this is not possible, use a shared resource like writing to a file/DB and the read value from there.